# Force Safari to open in fullscreen

Tags: macos, safari, applescript, automator

I'd love Safari to open in fullscreen mode.

It doesn't look like Safari natively supports this.

After some research I thought the best alternative may be to run an AppleScript when Safari opens forcing Safari into fullscreen mode.

```
tell application "System Events" to tell process "Safari"
    set value of attribute "AXFullScreen" of window 1 to true
end tell
```

How can I run this script every time Safari starts?

Comment: I realized this after I posted a script solution. If I open Safari then set it to full screen mode...  If I quit Safari in full-screen mode and reopen, it will automatically reopen in full screen mode.

Comment: This doesn't happen for me. I am jealous

Answer (score 1):

You could save this script in ScriptEditor as an .app and name it something like "Safari Maximized.app".  Then every time you want to launch Safari in full screen mode, just launch your new app.  You may need to adjust the delay setting in the code.

This works for me in the latest version of Sierra

```
tell application "Safari" to activate
delay 1
tell application "System Events"
    perform action "AXPress" of button 2 of window 1 of application process "Safari"
end tell
```

Don't forget to allow access for your new app through gatekeeper

[image]

Comment: `delay 1` is frustrating, is there no way around that?

Comment: You can try removing that.  I only added it to give safari time to open before the command gets executed

Comment: Actually, I noticed, if I open Safari then set it to full screen mode...  If I quit Safari in full-screen mode and reopen, it will automatically reopen in full screen mode. It seems there may be no need to script it.

Comment: This doesn't happen for me.